# Do I need to filter all subqueries before joining very large tables for optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, filter, subquery

I have three tables that I'm trying to join with over a billion rows per table. Each table has an index on the billing date column. If I just filter the left table and do the joins, will the query run efficiently or do I need to put the same date filter in each subquery?

I.E. will the first query run much slower than the second query?

```
select item, billing_dollars, IC_billing_dollars
from billing
left join IC_billing on billing.invoice_number = IC_billing.invoice_number
where billing.date = '2019-09-24'

select item, billing_dollars, IC_billing_dollars
from billing
left join (select * from IC_billing where IC_billing.date = '2019-09-24') on billing.invoice_number = IC_billing.invoice_number
where billing.date = '2019-09-24'
```

I don't want to run this without knowing whether the query will perform well as there aren't many safeguards for poor performing queries. Also, if I need to write the query in the second way, is there a way to only have the date filter in one location rather than having it show up multiple times in the query?

Comment: Can you try IC_billing.billing.date in your first query and see the difference? Now as you didn't provide any alias for billing.date in your first query it is taking it from main table. However in your send query you have it different.

Comment: Any modern optimizer will treat both queries the same. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends.

Consider your query:

```
select b.item, b.billing_dollars, icb.IC_billing_dollars
from billing b left join
     IC_billing icb
     on b.invoice_number = icb.invoice_number
where b.date = '2019-09-24';
```

(Assuming I have the columns coming from the correct tables.)

The optimal strategy is an index on `billing(date, invoice_number)` -- perhaps also with `item` and `billing_dollars` to the index;  and `ic_billing(invoice_number)` -- perhaps with `IC_billing_dollars`.

I can think of two situations where filtering on date in `ic_billing` would be useful.

First, if there is an index on `(invoice_date, invoice_number)`, particularly a primary key definition.  Then using this index is usually preferred, *even if another index is available*.

Second, if `ic_billing` is partitioned by `invoice_date`.  In that case, you will want to specify the partition for performance.

Generally, though, the additional restriction on the invoice date does not help.  In some databases, it might even hurt performance (particularly if the subquery is materialized and the outer query does not use an appropriate index).